# How should a minimax based agent with limited info guess a card in Cambio?

Tags: artificial-intelligence, probability, minimax, expectiminimax

I need help deciding what a minimax based agent should do in the following scenraio. In the card game of Cambio, two players are dealt four cards each from a deck of 52 cards . At the start of the game, the bottom cards of each player are observed and there are four hidden top cards (two in each player's hand). I am using minimax for my AI where a shallow copy of the game object is generated. Then possible moves are calculated based on the dealt card from the top of the deck. If 7,8 was at the top of the deck, our AI is able to peek a card in its hand(enemy’s hand if the card is 9 or 10). The problem is we are not allowed to reveal the card.

We could decide that our Ai has to guess the probabilities of every card type that could be the card we want to reveal. I was thinking of adding a system that counts how many cards each type has left. Then again we run into a problem of hidden cards in players' hands.

For example, here:

```
X      , X
Heart 7, spades 8, 

X      , X
spades 9, diamond 7.
```

x's are hidden.
Should AI guess the card above Heart 7? We would have to assume that either all the hidden cards are of type 7, none of the cards are or some of the cards are of type 7. I feel like if we try to "guess" the card, then computation will branch out in different assumptions slowing our agent.